# Hiding "View Menu" button in RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My RCP application includes the Project Explorer view, which has several small buttons in its top-right corner (e.g. "Minimize", "Maximize", "View Menu").

I would like to remove the "View Menu" button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think "activities" is what you need:

You should check this:
http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/

Comment: That is what I would have hoped. However, some UI elements (including the "Vew Menu" button) do not have unique IDs - they are not added to the UI via a plugin.xml file. This can be confirmed by inspecting them using the Plugin Spy. Therefore, they cannot be referenced by an activity.

Comment: That's really disappointing! Personally, I don't know other ways to hide menus... I'm afraid that the only way is to import the project explorer's plugin in your workspace and remove the menu by directly making your version of it! Sorry for not being of any help!